# My grease pencil is either 100% or 0% influenced in weight painting

Tags: rigging, grease-pencil

I have a really basic mesh, and I've sketched some grease pencil detail over the top (in this specific case, a mesh head with grease pencil facial features). I can rig and weight paint the mesh so that moving a bone deforms it organically, with the influence going from 100% to 0% naturally. My issue is that when I try and weight paint the grease pencil in the same way, using a gradient of influences, it acts as either 100% or 0% influence. In the example of the mesh head, I can raise the eyebrows, and the mesh deforms smoothly with some areas moving more than others, but the GP detail acts more like a parented object on top.

I've seen videos and tutorials of GP rigging (eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3zRJ6904i0&t=91s), where the characters have bendy limbs with areas of 50% influence, but when I follow them I don't seem to get the same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: GP vertices can have smooth weight painting. Generally when a vertex moves rigidly it's because it is weighted to one vertex group only. Try adding some weight to a general "Head" vertex group also.

Comment: Thank you so much! This had been annoying me for a while, but this solved it immediately. Much appreciated!